# Elastic Beanstalk Laravel 5.4 Worker HTTP 500

Tags: amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, worker

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and after applying [this package](https://github.com/dusterio/laravel-aws-worker) to my project and deploying it to my Elastic Beanstalk environment, messages in my sqs stay always in flight. I've done everything that the readme file says...

I followed every step but still got error 500 on POST /worker/queue requests.

Here's my worker log:

```
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [21/Jun/2017:01:36:59 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 200 92 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [21/Jun/2017:01:37:59 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 200 92 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [21/Jun/2017:01:38:59 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 200 92 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [21/Jun/2017:01:39:59 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 200 92 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [21/Jun/2017:01:39:54 +0000] "POST /worker/queue HTTP/1.1" 500 84128 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [21/Jun/2017:01:40:59 +0000] "POST /worker/schedule HTTP/1.1" 200 92 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [21/Jun/2017:01:41:13 +0000] "POST /worker/queue HTTP/1.1" 500 84128 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [21/Jun/2017:01:41:13 +0000] "POST /worker/queue HTTP/1.1" 500 84128 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [21/Jun/2017:01:41:13 +0000] "POST /worker/queue HTTP/1.1" 500 84128 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [21/Jun/2017:01:41:13 +0000] "POST /worker/queue HTTP/1.1" 500 84128 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [21/Jun/2017:01:41:13 +0000] "POST /worker/queue HTTP/1.1" 500 84128 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"
```

Comment: If you don't mind please share you code also

Answer (score 0):

I have also been experiencing similar issues, and while I would need you to post some code, and more details as to what your doing, I can describe the steps I took to resolve my own issues.

You will need to be able to log into your instance in order to do some faster troubleshooting, so I suggest you set up eb ssh on your machines, or if you are using a VPC, create a Bastion host, to use to connect to the internal EC2s. Log into the app environment, go to /var/www/html, run php artisan tinker, and manually dispatch a job. If you are successful you will get a response with the id of the queued message, if not you will receive an error output, which you can further use to troubleshoot the issue. I also suggest checking whether the app is picking up the environmental values for the queues, so check whether the queue you set in the deployment configuration, matches the one your app is trying to send the request to.

If the message is successfully being sent to the queue, but you still have failing jobs, I suggest you SSH into the worker environment EC2 machine, and try to dispatch a job from there as well. In my personal scenario the worker environment was in the wrong security group, so it didn't have access to the database, resulting in a 500 error, due to an internal server issue.

Instructions on creating bastion hosts:
https://vaughanj10.github.io/creating-a-bastion-host-for-aws/